# Temporary debug releases and final application releases

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2008, debugging, release

I have a quick question regarding debug and release in VS 2008.

I have an app i've been working on - its not yet complete but the bulk of the functionality is there. So basically i'm trying to give a copy of it now to the person helping with documentation - just so they can have a play and get the feel for what i've made.

Now the question is how to provide it to them. I was told to just copy the .exe out of the debug/bin folder and put that onto USB. But when testing, if I run this .exe anywhere else (outside of this folder) it crashes. I've now worked out why this is:

```
var path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PathToUse"];
var files = Directory.GetFiles(path);
```

throws a null reference, so that App.config file is not being used. If I copy that file in with the .exe it works again.

So actually my question is regarding the best way to manage this situation. What is the best way to provide a working copy to people, and, is there a reference on preparing apps for release - so everything is packaged together and installed in a clean structured folder heirarchy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be safe grab everything in the debug/bin folder.  If you use the drop down in VS to change to release and then compile the project, there will be fewer files in the release/bin folder because many debug related files are not included.

If there are third party DLLs you are referencing, like if you downloaded log4net or something like that, then you can simply put them in the same folder as the exe.  This is called side-by-side deployment, and in my opinion is the simplest and easiest to test.

You can search for XCOPY deployment to learn more about what you are trying to do.

You can take another step of compressing the bin folder into an archive like a zip file to make it easy for the user to extract them, or you could use a tool like WIX or NSIS to create an installer to extract and copy the files.

Comment: Also if there are files not in the debug/bin and/or release/bin folder, then you may need to select the file in VS and there will be an option in the properties of the file telling it to be copied when the project is compiled.  This is what makes it appear in the bin folder.  Note also that these configurations are seperate for Release and Debug, you will need to switch the drop down to Release and make the same change again so that your release and debug biuilds behave the same.  It is like this because there may be occasions that something is needed for debug but not release.

Comment: or one could pick the "all configurations" option before setting the option, so that one does not have to set it more than once. (Of course, I usually don't remember to do this until I've already changed it in Debug...)

Comment: @SamB LOL Me to, and I don't realize it until later when something is out of whack.